# How can i minimize repeated code with function?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
float qwer4 = 0;

NSNumberFormatter *eFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[eFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

[eFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

NSString *formattede = [eFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:qwer4]];

self.eLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",formattede];//





float qwer6 = qwer4*6/100; 

NSNumberFormatter *pFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[pFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

[pFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

NSString *formattedpTax = [pFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:qwer6]];

self.pLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",formattedp];




NSNumberFormatter *tFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[tFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

[tFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

NSString *formattedtTax = [tTaxFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:qwer4 + qwer6]];

self.tLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",formattedt];
```

- (void) repeated
  {
  NSNumberFormatter *tFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

  [tFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

  [tFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

  NSString *formattedt = [tTaxFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:??]];

  self.tLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",formattedt];
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create only a single `NSNumberFormatter` object and use it in all three places. That will shorten your code and make it look a lot cleaner.

Comment: As well as be far more efficient.

Comment: thanks, removed 3000 lines of code

Comment: i thought 1 NSNumberFormatter for 1 object